# XPath to get CSS classes with attributes

Tags: html, xpath

I need to get the CSS classes, `c1`, `c2`, etc. with their corresponding attributes, but I can't figure it out. Can it be done or is CSS out of XPath's reach?

Example:

```
<style type="text/css">&#13;
    p.c6 {font-weight: bold; text-align: left}&#13;
    p.c5 {font-weight: bold}&#13;
    p.c4 {text-align: left}&#13;
    td.c3 {font-weight: bold}&#13;
    p.c2 {text-align: center}&#13;
    p.c1 {font-weight: bold; text-align: center}&#13;
</style>
```

Comment: Maybe this can be of any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119779/how-to-write-a-csv-parser-using-xslt-1-0 It's an example of a CSV parser; the same approach should work for your problem.

Comment: This cannot be produced with a single XPath 1.0 expression, but it can be expressed with a single XPath 2.0 expression and/or XSLT. Are you interested in an XPath 2.0 or XSLT (1.0 or 2.0) solution?

Comment: i am using lxml that should support xslt 1.0, if there's a way to do it, i would appriciate it.